# populate a search field with jquery (live search)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, search

I am trying to make a live search of users or what have you based on querying the database and returning an array then formatting it in a drop down and outputting it to the user in realtime with ajax. Thus far below is my code. The issue is everytime I run a search where the `suggestions` should be the page loads again within the `div`. [image: issue]
Furthermore, no search results appear.

Here is the code:

PHP (housed in same page as js):

```
<?php
/* User Search */
if (isset($_POST['userSearch'])):
    $string = $_POST['userSearch'];
    if (strlen($string) > 3):
        $sql = "SELECT id, user_name, user_email, full_name FROM users WHERE MATCH (user_name) AGAINST ({$string}* IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY user_name LIMIT 10";
        $display = '';
        if ($result = Nemesis::query($sql)):
            $result->fetch_assoc();
            $display .= '<ul id="searchresults">';
            foreach ($result as $row):
                $link = 'index.php?do=users&amp;action=edit&amp;userid=' . (int) $row['id'];
                $display .= '<li><a href="' . $link . '">' . $row['user_name'] . '<small>' . $row['full_name'] . ' - ' . $row['user_email'] . '</small></a></li>';
            endforeach;
            $display .= '</ul>';
            print $display;
            exit();
        endif;
    endif;
endif;
?>
```

JS:

```
$("#search-input").watermark("Search Username");
$("#search-input").keyup(function () {
    var srch_string = $(this).val();
    var data_string = 'userSearch=' + srch_string;
    if (srch_string.length > 3) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "",
            data: data_string,
            beforeSend: function () {
                $('#search-input').addClass('loading');
            },
            success: function (res) {
                $('#suggestions').html(res).show();
                $("input").blur(function () {
                    $('#suggestions').customFadeOut();
                });
                if ($('#search-input').hasClass("loading")) {
                    $("#search-input").removeClass("loading");
                }
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

CSS:

```
<style>
/* == Live Search == */
#suggestions{position:absolute;z-index:800;left:20px}
#searchresults{position:relative;border-radius:5px;-moz-border-radius:5px;-webkit-border-radius:5px;background-color:#F3F3F3;width:250px;margin-top:7px;left:0;z-index:800;border:1px solid #ccc;background-image:url(../images/td-bg.png);background-repeat:repeat-x;background-position:left top;padding:5px}
#searchresults a small{display:block;line-height:1.2em;color:#999;font-size:12px}
#searchresults a{display:block;text-decoration:none;padding:3px}
#searchresults a:hover{text-decoration:none;background-color:#FFF;border-radius:4px;-moz-border-radius:4px;-webkit-border-radius:4px}
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="searchDiv">
<input name="search-input" type="text" class="input" id="search-input" size="40" style="width:240px" onclick="disAutoComplete(this);">
<div id="suggestions"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why aren't you using jQuery-UI's Autocomplete widget?

Comment: You have position:absolute on #suggestions but no positioning on #searchDiv. Do you want them to be disconnected?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by: "The issue is everytime I run a search where the suggestions should be the page loads again within the div". Does the whole page reload when you enter letters in the search input? Which div does it load within?

Comment: yes. as you can see the entire page loads again. without the search results